# Как получить картинку из input в electronjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Я почти не работал с nodejs а тем более с electronjs. Поэтому не понимаю как происходит передача файлов. То есть у меня есть `<input type='file'>` и нужно этот файл сохранить в определенную папку. Подскажите как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала нужно взять путь до файла. Electronjs его выдает вот так

```
let url_file = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0].path
```

Затем копируем с помощью библиотеки fs

```
fs.copyFile( url_file, "test.jpg", (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(true);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

используй node.js  А ИМЕННО МОДУЛЬ FS  https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html для работы с файлами

```
// ДАННЫЕ КАРТИНКИ
fs.writeFile('c://FOLDER/image.png', data, 'binary', function(err){
            if (err) throw err
            console.log('File saved.')
        })
```

Comment: а как из Input взять путь до файла ?

Comment: в node много есть модуль path думаю там есть то что надо

Comment: а если без ноды то не как

Comment: ну по сути можно и через js. Просто нужно использовать electron

Comment: К примеру беру из input value и там это "C:\fakepath\1.jpg" когда пытаюсь это скопировать, выкидывает ошибку что такого файла нету.

Comment: это спец фэйковый путь делается. js не имеет парва на рабоут с файлами

Comment: а как эти права получить ?

Comment: ни как не получить